# How to search a file using every line of another file and append one field of the resulting matches

Tags: shell, scripting

For a file with two columns of data (file1) that looks like this:

```
1232323 dog 
21321   cat
21321   fox
2312323 bird
```

And a second file with two columns of data (file2) that looks like this:

```
dog red
cat blue
fox green
bird black
```

I am trying to write a script that will use iterate through every entry in column 2 of file1 to to find matching entries from column 1 of file2, and creates a third file that appends the data from column 2 of file2 to the searches that have "hit" like this:

```
1232323 dog red
21321   cat blue
21321   fox green
2312323 bird black
```

Here is some pseudocode:

```
For each string in field 2 of file1
    grep file2
    output field1 and field2 of file1 and matching field2 of file2 from any hits to file3
```

Thank you.

Comment: What scripting language do you want to use? What environment (linux/windows/mac/os Z from outer space)?

Comment: I would prefer bash shell, but any shell or PERL script that can do it would be welcome. The environment is CentOS Linux. Thanks!

Comment: read about the `join` command. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

this one-liner may help:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$2}' f1 f2
1232323 dog  red
21321   cat blue
21321   fox green
2312323 bird black
```

or with join:

```
kent$  join -12 -21 -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 f1 f2
1232323 dog red
21321 cat blue
21321 fox green
2312323 bird black
```

Comment: the one liner gives me a blank output file for some reason - I will try the join!

Comment: I'm not sure that the join should work because there isn't a line-by-line correspondence between f1 and f2. f2 has many more entries than f1.

Comment: I tried it just for grins, and I got an error when running the join:join: file 2 is not in sorted order
join: file 1 is not in sorted order

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest bash-only solution is likely going to make use of an associative array, which requires bash > 4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A num_data
while read -r num animal; do
    num_data["$animal"]="$num"
done < file1

declare -A color_data
while read -r animal color; do
    color_data["$animal"]="$color"
done < file2

for i in "${!num_data[@]}"; do
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "${num_data[$i]}" "$i" "${color_data[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: I do have >bash4, but get an error: ./bash_array: line 5: num_data["$animal"]: bad array subscript

Comment: That would be the error I would expect to see if you bash did _not_ support associative arrays.  Does a simpler example work? `declare -A foo=([bar]=baz); echo "${foo[bar]}"`

Comment: Try dropping the quotes in the assignments: `color_data[$animal]="$color"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
# Usage:  perl datafind.pl > file3.txt

open FILE1, "<file1.txt" or die $!;
my @lines1 = <FILE1>;
close FILE1 or die $!;

open FILE2, "<file2.txt" or die $!;
my @lines2 = <FILE2>;
close FILE2 or die $!;

foreach(@lines1) {
    my($col11, $col12) = split(/\s+/);
    foreach(@lines2) {
        my($col21, $col22) = split(/\s+/);
        if($col12 eq $col21) {
            print "$col11 $_";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `join` command is what you need, but the input files need to be sorted. Using process substitution:

```
join -1 2 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 <(sort -b -k2 file1) <(sort file2)
```

produces

```
2312323  bird  black
21321    cat   blue
1232323  dog   red
21321    fox   green
```

I piped the join command into `column -t` to make the output pretty.